# Como verificar se uma classe implementa uma interface, em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, reflexão

Como verificar se uma classe implementa uma interface?

Por exemplo, quero incluir um if que verifica se um objeto é do tipo IDisposable. Como fazer?

Tentei algo do tipo :

```
        MinhaClasse meuObjeto = new MinhaClasse();
        if (typeof(meuObjeto) == IDisposable)
        {

        }
```

Mas não rolou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta nesta [pergunto do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface) na resposta do [Robert c barth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209/robert-c-barth)

> ```
> if (object is IBlah)
> ```
>
> ou
>
> ```
> IBlah myTest = originalObject as IBlah
>
> if (myTest != null)
> ```

Comment: Legal. Pergunta : Na segunda alternativa, se o originalObject não implementar IBlah vai gerar alguma Exception?

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos Não, o objetivo dos operadores `is` e `as` é justamente evitar a exceção. Com o `as` ou a operação de "conversão" é realizada ou o objeto não é criado. Por isso é necessário verificar se ele é `null` em seguida. Ou seja, se `originalObject` não implementar `IBlah`, `myTest` será nulo e qualquer tentativa de acessá-lo, gerará uma `NullReference Exception` ou alguma outra mais especializada. O `is` só é usado se você precisa saber se implementa a interface mas não vai fazer uma conversão, ou seja o próprio objeto precisa implementá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Com [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183.aspx) é fácil identificar se o objeto de uma classe foi implementado com a *interface* `IDisposable`, inclusive, pode-se verificar se existem mais implementações dessa forma

*Classe*

```
public class Mecanismo: IDisposable
{        
   public void Dispose()
   {

   }
}
```

*Código*

```
Mecanismo mecanismo = new Mecanismo();
Type mectype = mecanismo.GetType();
var c = mectype.GetInterface("System.IDisposable"); //forma direta
if (c != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sim, foi implementado");
}
//ou
if (mectype.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("IDisposable")).Any())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sim, foi implementado");
}
```

---

Exemplo Online: [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/n6Y7mN)